# Django CMS annonying error

Tags: python, django, error-handling, content-management-system, django-cms

I have a simple search app within a Django project which searches within a CMS admin. This is the form that generates the URL:

```
< form method="get" action="/search">
            < p>< label for="id_q">Search:
            < input type="text" name="q" id="id_q" />
            < input type="submit" value="Submit" />< /p>
```

, this is the URL:

```
(r'^search/$', 'search.views.search'),
```

this is the view:

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET['q']
    results = FlatPage.objects.filter(content__icontains=query)
    template = loader.get_template('search/search.html')
    context = Context({ 'query': query, 'results': results })
    response = template.render(context)
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

, this is the template:

```
< html>
    < head>
        < title>Search page
    < /head>
    < body>
        < p>You searched for "{{ query }}"; the results are listed below.< /p>
        < ul>
            {% for page in results %}
                < li>< a href="{{ page.get_absolute_url }}">{{ page.title }}< /a>< /li>
            {% endfor %}
        < /ul>
    < /body>
< /html>
```

but I keep receiving this error :

```
"Key 'q' not found in < QueryDict: {} >"
```

. Does anyone why and what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably this error is happening when you first request the page, before you submit a search term - so obviously, the `q` field is not found in the request. You just need to check for it first:

```
def search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        query = request.GET['q']
        results = FlatPage.objects.filter(content__icontains=query)
```

Comment: Apache says: if response.status_code == 404: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'/

Answer (score 1):

You are using request.GET when you are posting the results in the submit.  Use both the check mentioned by Daniel AND use POST instead:

```
def search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET:
      query = request.GET['q']
      results = FlatPage.objects.filter(content__icontains=query)
    else:
      query = ""
      results = None
    template = loader.get_template('search/search.html')
    context = Context({ 'query': query, 'results': results })
    response = template.render(context)
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

Comment: I've tried it with both GET and POST, but it doesn't seem to work. Apache spits that same error: if response.status_code == 404: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'/

Comment: Try the modified code.  You are using method='get' in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the line from `query = request.GET['q']` to `query = request.GET.get('q')`

Note the `get()` function... Of course the other answers here also would work. See this similar question:

['instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666408/instancemethod-object-has-no-attribute-getitem)