# 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: django, django-views

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

With my particular view on a django site I am playing around with. I have no idea why but I have a feeling it might be related to the way I am retrieving a specific object from a model.

The error occurs here:

```
def myview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tel = request.POST.get['tel_number']
        person = get_object_or_404(Employee,phone_number=tel) # HERE
```

I have an Employee model with `phone_number` as a `CharField` as such:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

The request.POST data is sent from an android application. All I want to do is to retrieve an Employee object that has a particular phone_number value.

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is in this line `tel = request.POST.get['tel_number']`. If you are using `.get` you should pass the key as an argument:

```
tel = request.POST.get('tel_number') # if key is not present by default it will return None
```

Otherwise you can do this:

```
tel = request.POST['tel_number'] # raise KeyError Exception if key is not present in dict
```

Comment: Hmm, no luck so far: I used: tel = request.POST.get['tel_number'], same typeError when I send the post data, with a key of 'tel_number'

Comment: Please see clearly. I am using `()` parenthesis not this `[]`. so it should be `tel = request.POST.get('tel_number')`

Comment: Scratch that, it worked (I should've read the errors more closely, it is a new one now but one that I understand!), thank you for your patience Aamir

Comment: If i have to send an array through the ajax call using GET method... What changes would i have to do?