# Internal Server 500 Error - Django

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to create a like button, but when I click the button, I get the following error: `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/like/ajax/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)`.

When I look in my console, the problem traces back to this line in my `views.py`: `like_item_id = request.POST.get['photo_id']`

Could someone please point me in the right direction to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `request.POST.get['photo_id']`, which is incorrect since it the `.get` here is the method to extract the dict's values if the key is passed.

So, either directly access the key from the `request.POST` dict:

```
request.POST['photo_id']
```

Or, if you want to use the get method, use it as a proper method call (this way is preferred since it has the inherent fail-safe that it won't throw exception if the key doesn't exist):

```
request.POST.get('photo_id', '')
```

Comment: If I do request.POST.get('photo_id', '') I get this error: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'. If I do the other way, I get a multiValueDictKeyError. Any ideas?

Comment: @jph Can you print `request.POST` within the `if request.is_ajax() and request.POST` and tell me its value?

Comment: the value: <QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'D7IcLY0BJ0a9mQIMahToXql1XZnvOQvp']}>

Comment: Just to update, I fixed the multiValue error (typo in the imports). However, the data is still not passing through correctly, as you can see. Would you happen to know how to fix that?

Comment: @jph There are two problems here, 1) the value of the photo_id is not being sent correctly (because of which it is not even present in the value you shared, and this has to be debugged on JS side, so check the requests being generated in your chrome/firebug console) and 2) The `__getitem__` error should not have occured, I am able to confirm that the exact same operation works in my project, and this has [been suggested earlier as well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15666476/1860929)..